# Runtime APIs and TypeDefs: Is there a possibility to filter data due to type definitions?

Tags: typescript, api, types, runtime, lodash

> **My assumption:** It should be possible to create some kind of guard from TypeDefs that will exist at runtime. I imagine that I read somewhere that it is somehow possible with TS4+.

**Actually two Questions, one of them should be solvable:**

1. If, e.g. your API (out of your control) gives you noisy data and you are trying to filter them due to existing type definitions, how would you go?
2. Sometimes, your type definitions can look weird, and you cannot easily filter by `lodash.keyBy` because the `iteratee` can have different shapes depending on the given TypeDefs.

**Example:**

You have an object type like this:

```
type ObjectType = {
  [key: string]: {
    foo?: string | number;
  };
};
```

Following data would pass due to the `ObjectType` above:

```
const someOKCollection: Array<ObjectType> = [
  { june: { foo: 1 } },
  { earth: {} },
  { milky: { foo: "Hi" } }
];
```

Imagine, that is coming from an API:

```
const collectionFromApi: Array<unknown> = [
  { car: { foo: 1 } },
  { soup: {} },
  { water: { foo: "Hi" } },
  { sun: { bar: "Hi" } }
];
```

In this case `sun` is unnecessary due to the `ObjectType` (because it has `bar`). And the exciting point is I need the data in form of:

```
const desiredResult = {
  noMatter: { foo: 1 },
  what: {},
  Ever: { foo: "Hi" }
};
```

**Final Question:**

Regardless of whether the first question is solvable, how should the `iteratee` be formed (automatically) from TypeDefiniton so that I use lodash.keyBy or some other collection function and get the desired goal?

**EDIT:** A simplified CodeSandBox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-lodash-types-6844w0?file=/src/index.type.ts (**please notice:** root key names can be different than a,b,c in runtime, only TypeDefs have to be respected)

Comment: I think, that goes in the direction, please check it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDEAjAVgU2LAXhgG8ZUYBycHCgGhgzQqgHcQ6ZgmoALAJxw0YAXwDcAKHEBLAGYwAFDwQQAylD5SwAcwDSOAJ4R5iZPQDaFBBwoZrwCgF0AlE5LiYHzuAggANjgA6XxAteTN4JAQAhHoTKOBYyICMGAcArBBNeWsXCWFJGQBXMHwpcBglVXVNXQMIGAAeHRgcAA8oHDA4eugNbQA+BTi0BDB9egBrOrQdM2c0OJgpeoAlPBA+OCb6XprB4ndPGQ2FUEhYKf10OUuIVwPPR6W5eSh9AAccEDk4s0uHGAAQgIRAou20FHuhyeTwEUEKfDAMBkCF8EBwEhhHnyjxxnjhCKR6kKGPEwiAA

Answer (score 0):

Without lodash:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-lodash-types-forked-11io7p?file=/src/index.type.ts

```js
// import keyBy from "lodash/fp/keyBy";

type ObjectType = {
  [key: string]: {
    foo?: string | number;
  };
};

// const someOKCollection: Array<ObjectType> = [
//   { a: { foo: 1 } },
//   { b: {} },
//   { c: { foo: "Hi" } }
// ];

const collectionFromApi: unknown[] = [
  { a: { foo: 1 } },
  { b: {} },
  { c: { foo: "Hi" } },
  { d: { bar: "Hi" } }
];

type AllowedKey = "a" | "b" | "c";
const allowedKeys = new Set<AllowedKey>(["a", "b", "c"]);

// const desiredResult = {
//   a: { foo: 1 },
//   b: {},
//   c: { foo: "Hi" }
// };

type Result = {
  [key in AllowedKey]: { foo?: string | number };
};

const y = collectionFromApi.reduce<Result>((acc, val) => {
  if (typeof val !== "object" || val === null) return acc;

  const key = Object.keys(val)[0];

  if (
    key === undefined ||
    !allowedKeys.has(key as AllowedKey)
  ) {
    return acc;
  }

  acc[key as AllowedKey] = (val as Result)[key as AllowedKey];
  return acc;

}, {} as Result);
console.log("Y", y);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alexey, but as you notice, the root keys are not known and may change. I'm trying to find a solution, that can deal with it automatically.

Comment: @Lonely if you have sample of an object that you need to get (not type), it is possible. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's only an example above; the generation of an iteratee from TypeDefs is the main question.